# Linux equivalent of WinCrypt API

Tags: linux, authentication, smartcard, x509

when I need to authenticate client applications against X.509 protected SSL, TLS and SSH based servers in Windows, I use the WinCrypt functions to handle the certificate interfacing functionality.

What is the equivalent of WinCrypt for Linux?, I'm looking for smartcard or secure usb token based APIs where possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) and [GnuTLS](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnutls/) provide full X.509/SSL/TLS cryptographic functionality, while also supporting smart cards via the [OpenSC](http://www.opensc-project.org/opensc) library.

I am not sure what authenticating against an SSH server implies, but you may want to have a look at the [OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.com/) project.

Comment: Thanks for the response but it's not encryption or digital signature  APIs that I'm worried about, it's access to the secure tokens which contain the X.509 certificates

Comment: @Gearoid Murphy: Did you have a look at the OpenSC library that I mentioned?

Comment: Technically you can use PKCS#11 with OpenSSL as well (engine_pkcs11, pkcs11-helper) but I'd avoid building against OpenSSL as "the default API". Have a look at http://p11-glue.freedesktop.org/ as well.

Comment: Ah, OpenSC is what I was looking for, I contacted Ludovic Rousseau of pcsc-lite last night and he recommended the same API, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

PKCS#11 is probably the only real alternative for anything meaningful on Linux, especially if considering hardware access, unfortunately. The typical strength/problem of Linux: too many projects to choose from. And one can only be standard in a K or G world.

Comment: K or G world?, what does this mean?

Answer (score 2):

I know nothing about Windows. But perhaps [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) could help you.

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't more precise in my question, I had meant to refer to authentication subsystems like 'pcsc-lite', specifically C++ APIs for those types of authentication subsystems.